# How can I shuffle a dataset in incanter?

Tags: clojure, incanter

How can I shuffle a incanter dataset?

```
(shuffle (:rows data-set))
```

Only returns a clojure vector of maps.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
(col-names data-set)
(dataset (col-names data-set)
         (shuffle (:rows data-set)))
```

Attention: `dataset` is the incanter data set type. While `data-set` is a instance of that type which contains my data.